# Rationale of C# iterators design (comparing to C++)

Tags: c#, iterator

I found similar topic:
[Iterators in C++ (stl) vs Java, is there a conceptual difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347/iterators-in-c-stl-vs-java-is-there-a-conceptual-difference)

Which basically deals with Java iterator (which is similar to C#) being unable to going backward.

So here I would like to focus on limits -- in C++ iterator does not know its limit, you have by yourself compare the given iterator with the limit. In C# iterator knows more -- you can tell without comparing to any external reference, if the iterator is valid or not.

I prefer C++ way, because once having iterator you can set any iterator as a limit. In other words if you would like to get only few elements instead of entire collection, you don't have to alter the iterator (in C++). For me it is more "pure" (clear).

But of course MS knew this and C++ while designing C#. So what are the advantages of C# way? Which approach is more powerful (which leads to more elegant functions based on iterators). What do I miss?

If you have thoughts on C# vs. C++ iterators **design** other than their limits (boundaries), please also answer.

**Note**: (just in case) please, keep the discussion strictly technical. No C++/C# flamewar.

## EDITS

As Tzaman put it "There's no benefit to having the limit be expressed separately, because there's no way to get there except walking one element at a time." However it is not that difficult to built a C# iterator which does several steps a time, thus the question -- is  there a benefit of having explicit limit iterator (as in C++)? If yes -- what?

### @Jon,

*Edit1:* let's say you have a function foo which does something on iterators (the example is very naive!)

```
void foo(iter_from,iter_end) // C++ style
void foo(iter) // C# style
```

And now you would like to call function bar on all elements except last 10.

```
bar(iter_from,iter_end-10); // C++ style
```

In C# (if I am not mistaken) you would have to provide extra method for this iterator to change *its* limit, something like this:

```
bar(iter.ChangeTheLimit(-10));
```

*Edit2:* After rereading of your post, I sense crucial difference. In C++ you work on iterators of collection, in C# you work on collections (iterator is used "internally"). If yes, I still feel a bit uncomfortable with C# -- you iterate the collection and when you find interesting element you would like to pass all elements from "here" to end. In C++ it is very easy and there is no overhead. In C# you either pass an iterator or a collection (if the latter there will be extra computing). I'll wait for your comment :-)

### @Hans,

I am not comparing apples and oranges. The comp. theory is common ground here, so you have sort algorithm, partition, etc. You have the notion of collection (or sequence, as Jon likes). Now -- the matter is how you design the access to the elements to have elegant algorithm written in C# or C++ (or any other language). I would like to understand the reasoning "we did this, because...".

I know .NET iterators and collections are separate classes. I know the difference between access to an element and entire collection. However in C++ the most general way to work on a collection is working with iterators -- this way you can work with list and vector despite those collections are completely different. In C# on the other hand you rather write

```
sort(IEnumerable<T> coll)
```

function instead

```
sort(IEnumerator<T> iter)
```

correct? So in this sense I guess you cannot take C# iterators as C++ iterators, because C# does not express the same algorithms the same way as C++ does. Or as Jon pointed out -- in C# you rather transform collection (Skip, Take) instead of changing iterators.

Comment: @macias, as being neither a C++ or C# developer, I prefer the C# style in your example. It looks more natural to me.

Comment: How are infinite sequences dealt with in C++? What would iter_end be in such circumstances?

Comment: @Damien, I never worked with infinitive sequence in C++.

Comment: Two words: Responsibility principle.

Comment: @Damien: for infinite sequences, `iter_end` just has to be a special value that will never be reached (for example, an istream_iterator can denote an infinite range if the stream never ends). However, if an algorithm is designed to work with an infinite sequence, it should probably take only one iterator. For example, the algorithm `std::copy` takes two input iterators denoting the source range (or sequence), but only one output iterator, which can be more or less seen as an infinite range where the copy will be made. [...]

Comment: [...] Iterators that generate values can also be seen as iterators on an infinite sequence. I think in Boost they call this a "lazy sequence" (see for instance boost::counting_iterator, which generates incremental values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges.  The STL collection classes had completely different design goals.  They are a one-size-fits-all design to collections, you can only ever get the classes that are provided.  There's no way to customize a collection, the STL classes were not designed to be inherited from.

Very different from the .NET ones, their core is the ICollection, IDictionary and IList interfaces.  The .NET framework contains hundreds of collection classes, customized to get their specific job done.

That affected the designs of their iterators as well.  STL iterators *must* provide a lot of flexibility since the collections they iterate cannot be customized.  There is an inherent cost associated with that.  There are 5 different STL iterator types, not all collection classes support all 5 different types.  Loss of generality is never a good thing in a library design.

While an argument can be made that C++ iterators are more flexible, I'll make the opposite assertion.  The simplicity of IEnumerator was an enabler for very valuable .NET features.  The C# yield keyword for example, it completely disassociates a collection with the behavior of an iterator.  Linq would not have happened if it wasn't for a simple iterator type.  Covariance support would not have been possible.

Regarding your *Edit2*, no, .NET iterators are separate classes, just like the C++ ones.  Make sure to understand the difference between IEnumerable (implemented by the collection) and IEnumerator (implemented by the iterator).

Comment: Ok, a lot will go to edit :-) I think you get me convinced with yield example. I.e. with two iterators for defining the boundaries you have to know in advance the limit (the limit can change, but it has to be there). So yield counterpart would have to transfer two values each time, meaning current iterator would have to know its limit --> which leads us to C# iterator. Nice.

Comment: I respectfully posit that this is a bad answer.  Firstly, you are factually incorrect about STL collections and iterators: of course they can be inherited and customized.  The STL is designed to separate algorithms from structure - that is to say, the `std::copy` or `std::for_each` functions shouldn't have to care what its arguments are pointing to, only that they are valid iterators.  You are also wrong about C#: there are no iterators, only collections.

Comment: Well, ok.  I should clarify: the IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T> interfaces expose a method called `GetEnumerator` which returns an object implementing `IEnumerator` , which exposes a method called `MoveNext`.  However, this enumerator is not really the same thing as an iterator.

Answer (score 7):

It feels to me like the C# design is more encapsulated: a sequence runs out or does, independent of anything else. Where does it make *sense* to compare one limit with another?

If you only want to take a few elements, then LINQ provides any number of ways of building one sequence from another, e.g.

```
foo.Take(10)
foo.Skip(10)
foo.Where(x => x.StartsWith("y"))
```

etc

I think it's clearer - and more composable - to transform one sequence into another than to specify this with limits. If you want to pass an iterator to another function, but you want to restrict it to the first few elements, why should you have to *also* pass a limit? Why not just pass the transformed sequence which self-limits?

EDIT: To address your question edit: in C# (at least with LINQ) you wouldn't modify the existing collection. You would create a new sequence from the old one. This is done lazily; it doesn't create a new copy or anything like that. For LINQ to Objects, this is performed using extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>`, so any sequence gains the same abilities.

Note that this isn't restricted to traditional collections - it could be a sequence of lines read from a log file (again, lazily). You don't need any knowledge of the collection itself, just that it's a *sequence* from which one can draw items. There's also the difference between an `IEnumerable<T>` and an `IEnumerator<T>` where the first represents the sequence and the second represents an iterator over a sequence; `IEnumerator<T>` is rarely used explicitly in C#, or passed around.

Now, your example of "all elements except the last 10" is a tricky one, because for a general sequence you can't tell that you're 10 elements from the end until you've reached the end. There's nothing in LINQ to Objects to do this explicitly. For anything implementing `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` you could use

```
Bar(list.Take(list.Count - 10))
```

but that's not very general. A more general solution would need to maintain a circular buffer of 10 elements, effectively reading 10 ahead of where it's yielding. I've rarely found this to be a requirement, to be honest.

Comment: Yeah...this definitely looks nicer, but what did they expect us to do *before* LINQ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your example and below you assumed your "input" is a collection. But what if it is already an iterator? Since comments do not format well, I edit my post.

Comment: @Mark: In C# 1 it would have been pretty ugly to do this. In C# 2 you could build your own pseudo-LINQ reasonably easily using iterator blocks - it would lack the conciseness of lambda expressions and extension methods though.

Comment: @Jon, I know it is not about modifying collection elements :-) Now, about the example -- you cannot rely on fact you get Count for free, for example for linked list it is O(n) to get it, so C++ in such case would be much faster. And besides, you again used _collection_ instead of _iterator_. So I am more and more curious -- if really C++ iterators are C# collections (not iterators) counterpart? Or maybe I rephrase my question -- C++ STL general functions (#include <algorithm>) work on iterators, C# STL would work on _collections_ instead, correct?

Comment: @macias: You get Count for O(1) in a .NET `LinkedList<T>`... and you're also assuming you can easily get to "10 from the end" in a linked list, which will require it to be a doubly-linked list. But yes, I'll acknowledge that in the case of a doubly-linked list which doesn't maintain a count, getting all but the final X elements is trickier in .NET. I can't say I've come across that exact situation though :) In terms of collections vs iterators: it would be more accurate to say that .NET APIs often work in terms of *sequences* rather than collections. Not every sequence is a normal collection.

Comment: An expression like list.end()-n is O(n) in a std::list as well.  And O(1) for a std::vector, just like List<>.  No difference there.

Comment: @Jon, so, C# STL counterpart would be based on sequences, not iterators. Ok, that's a shift for my thinking :-) Thank you.

@Hans, good point. The exact steps would differ though.

Answer (score 6):

I think as long as you're talking only about *forward* iterators, I like the C# way - the sequence knows its own limit, you can transform it easily via LINQ, and so on. There's no benefit to having the limit be expressed separately, because there's no way to *get there* except walking one element at a time.

However, C++ iterators are a lot more powerful - you can have bidirectional iterators, or random-access iterators, that let you do things that aren't possible with a one-way sequential iterator. A sequential iterator is in a sense a generalization of a *linked list*, while a random access iterator is a generalization of an *array*. That's why you can efficiently express algorithms like quicksort in terms of C++ iterators, while that would be impossible with an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Oh, I like your answer -- however could you please explain a bit the last statement. Or post a link to some ext. reference. About the various kinds of iterators -- one does not deny the other, i.e. you could have C# iterator (with limit), yet bidirectional.

Comment: For "random access iterator" you'd just use `IList<T>` of course. The reason for my +1 here was the idea of a bidirectional iterator, which .NET doesn't support. I can't say it's something I'd want terribly often, but it's definitely an interesting omission.

Comment: @Jon - of course; still an `IList<T>` is (in macias' terms) a representation of the _collection_ itself rather than a _position_ in that collection. I suppose the C++ iterator concept was the best way to expose a generic interface to a collection, without having actual interfaces in the language - definitely much better than forcing an ABC inherit just to be able to use STL `algorithm` / etc. Any guesses as to why there's no .NET `Deque<T>` / `IBidirectional`? They _are_ useful...

Comment: @tzman: In many cases you can just use a `LinkedList<T>` as a `Deque<T>` although that comes with a memory cost. I don't know why there isn't a circular buffer implementation, other than that implementing *anything* costs time... I suspect the value hasn't been deemed great enough.

Comment: Is there any reason why `IEnumerator<T>` shouldn't support an `int Move(int);` method which, for a non-negative value, would try to call `MoveNext` the specified number of times and return 0 if it could move the full amount, or the amount of shortfall if it couldn't (the latter amount being useful if multiple `IEnumerable<T>` collections are concatenated)?  Any `IEnumerator<T>` implementation could implement that method to call `MoveNext()` if nothing else, but many implementations could use alternative approaches orders of magnitude faster than repeated calls to `MoveNext`.

Comment: @supercat There is, it's called `Skip`. I'm pretty sure it's specialized to be `O(1)` for underlying `List` types, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @tzaman: The `Skip` extension method, like `Count`, is specialized to be O(1) for a few special cases, but those specializations totally fail if e.g. one uses the `Concat` extension method to join a ten-item iterator to the end of a million-item list.  By contrast, if `IEnumerator` had a `Move(int)` method, and one sought to move 1,000,005 items through the enumerator produced by the aforementioned concatenation, then it could ask the `List<T>.Enumerator` to move 1,000,005 items through the `List<T>`, have it report that it fell five short, and then move five items through the other iterator.

Comment: @tzaman: Such an approach wouldn't rely upon type-specific specializations, and would be able to deal efficiently with composite aggregations like those produced by `concat`--something that specializations wouldn't be able to handle because they can't see inside such aggregations.

Answer (score 3):

> So what are the advantages of C# way?

Encapsulation for one. It makes it more difficult to mess up your iteration limits if you do not set the iteration sequence manually.

C++ example:

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> b;
std::vector<int>::iterator ba = a.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator ea = a.end();
std::vector<int>::iterator bb = b.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator eb = b.end();
// lots of code here
for(auto itr = ba; itr != eb; itr++) // iterator tries to "cross" vectors
                                     // you get undefined behavior, depending 
                                     // on what you do with itr
```

> Which approach is more powerful (which
>   leads to more elegant functions based
>   on iterators).

That depends on what you mean by most powerful.

The C++ approach is more flexible.

The C# one is more difficult to misuse.

Comment: Your example is very convincing, thank you for that! Powerful = you can express most algorithms (sort, partition, find, any, all and so on) in clear fashion.

Comment: @macias: You can express partition, find, any and all with C# sequences as well (and incredibly easily, using lambda expressions).

Comment: For that definition C++ iterators are definitely more powerful. You have i/o iterators, specifying custom ranges for algorithms (` std::sort(c.begin(), c.begin()+3)`), use the same algorithms with iterators _and raw pointers_) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I found this topic because of the following problem. There is a sequence that needs to be forward iterated one element at a time. However, at certain points a large number of elements needs to be skipped. When such skips occur, it is inefficient to do anything but jump and restart at the new index (i.e. it is not OK to run the loop for the skipped indices even without any loop body execution.)

Here's a C# snippet to give you the idea, except that it is using an int index rather than an enumerator.

```
for(int i = 0; i< 1000; ++i)
{
    ... // do something

    if (i == 100)
       i = 200; // skip from 100 to 200
}
```

The point is that going to the next element can be optimized for this particular sequence, but skipping elements (and all-out random access) is more costly. @Jon, using IList is therefore inefficient for this purpose. Yield doesn't directly allow this style either.

I tried various ways to do this in C# including using a lambda ForEach() style for the inner block, which returns the next index. However, this doesn't work very well.

The approach that will likely result in the least overhead is a simple iterator type - not based on IEnumerable or yield - that allows me to mimic the above code.

Thoughts?